# Spring WebClient is retrieving bad Content-Type

Tags: spring, webclient, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

When I run a WebClient as follows:

```
WebClient.create(apiUrl)
                .get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/some/{productId}/")
                        .queryParam("ws_key", apiKey)
                        .build(productId)
                )
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MyClass.class)
                .block();
```

The server return the header Content-Type with the value "text/html".

When I use Chrome to make the request, it returns correctly "text/xml" (it is a XML page).

I tried several "accept" parameters, and I am always getting "text/html".

Any idea on the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use `MediaType.TEXT_XML`? What does contain the `Accept` header in your Chrome request?

Comment: did you actually look into the response that you are getting xml back and that you are not getting an error msg with a html page, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `curl` to check it, add a `-H`to setup headers.

```sh
curl http://xxx/some/product -H "Accept:text/xml"
```

If it got the same result(html). I think the server side should be problematic.

When using a browser to access the APIs, I think its `accept` header is set to "*/*, text/html" sequence or similarly by default.

If the server side is controlled by yourself, set the content type of response body explicitly.